# Foreign Key references multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables :

```
--table A
ID INT
Description VARCHAR(8000)

--table B
ID INT
Description VARCHAR(8000)

--table C
ID INT
ObjectID INT
Type CHAR(1)
```

`ObjectID` column in `table C` contains `ID` from either `table A` or `table B`, for example

```
ID          ObjectID    Type
----------- ----------- ----
3           10          A
```

Result above means the `ID` with value `10` is coming from `table A`. I need to put foreign key on `ObjectID` column that references to `ID` column in both `table A` and `table B`. Is this possible?

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables

Comment: [I've answered a similar question a while ago.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539129/a-flexible-foreign-key/30539462#30539462)

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1540629-3077-1.aspx