# how to refer to two different table with one attribute in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Here is the query I have attempted:

```
create table login_user
(
    user_id int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    password varchar(10),
    role varchar(10),
    no_ic varchar(12),
    primary key(user_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_product
    FOREIGN KEY (no_ic) REFERENCES supplier(no_ic),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer
    FOREIGN KEY (no_ic) REFERENCES customer(no_ic)
);
```

I have tried this query but it fails.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935402/sql-server-foreign-key-to-multiple-tables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server foreign key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935402/sql-server-foreign-key-to-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

AS the guys pointed up, this is a duplicated question
BUT anyway : "**A foreign key can only reference one table**"

If you want to work around your stuation, you can create one table that have suppliers and customers and add one column if '1' supplier if '0' customer

Then  use `FOREIGN KEY (no_ic) REFERENCES newTableName(no_ic)`